# Align check boxes in checkboxlist

Tags: css, asp.net, checkboxlist

I know this type of question has already been asked, but I can't seem to find an answer that satisfy me need.

[image: CheckboxList]

As you can see from the image, I have 2 issues:

1. "Italy" is not aligned with "Germany"
2. The countries are listed in 2 columns, although there is room for the last two check boxes below. I want them to be in 2 columns **if and only if** there's an overflow.

This is my code:

```
    <div style="width: 94.1%; height: 120px; overflow-y: scroll;background-
    color:#928571;border:groove;">
   <asp:CheckBoxList ID="CBListLang" runat="server"
     RepeatDirection="Vertical" RepeatColumns="2" RepeatLayout="Flow"
     OnSelectedIndexChanged="CBListLang_SelectedIndexChanged" AutoPostBack="true">
   </asp:CheckBoxList>
</div>
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change RepeatLayout to "Table"

Comment: Thanks, it solved the first issue, but it still show them in 2 columns although it can fit only in 1.

Comment: @RotemOrbach, Did you try removing the RepeatColumns="2"?. That attribute is used to set the number of columns in which the checkboxes are to be displayed.

Comment: Hmm. I'ts just occurred to me that I actually thought that this attribute had a complete different meaning :) I thought that it means that the checkboxes will be in 2 columns in an overflow situation, when in fact, it only means that 2 columns will be created, and the total number of checkboxes will be divided among them equally. Thank!

Answer (score 1):

@stark is right. If you set `RepeatLayout`  with `Flow`, it causes the `CheckBoxList` control to output a `<span>` element for the checkboxes with `<br>` elements, thus placing the checkboxes in rows. In this case, unless all of your data is the same size, the checkboxes will not be aligned vertically.Now, if you set the `RepeatLayout` attribute  to `Table`, it causes the `CheckBoxList` control to output an HTML table that contains the checkboxes. Using `Table` ensures the checkboxes are aligned vertically.

```
 <asp:CheckBoxList ... RepeatLayout="Table" > </asp:CheckBoxList>
```

If you want set all the checkboxes in one column, then remove the `RepeatColumns="2"` attribute, which is used to set the number of columns in which the checkboxes are to be displayed